# Simplify SQL row_to_json from inner join

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

We have a table `Things` with instances belonging to table `Projects` via `thing.project_id`.

When querying an instance of `Things`, we are returning a json representation of the parent `Project` record as a value on that instance.

Currently it looks like:

```
SELECT t.id,
(
  SELECT row_to_json(a.*)
  FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.name
  ) AS a
) AS project
FROM "Things" t
INNER JOIN "Projects" p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

This works fine, but it seems like it could be simplified.

Is there a way to get rid of the need for an intermediate variable (`a` in this example) while retaining clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want, but what about:

```
SELECT t.id, to_jsonb(p) as project
FROM "Things" t
 JOIN "Projects" p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

To exclude columns from the `project` table, you can use the `-` operator with `jsonb`:

```
SELECT t.id, to_jsonb(p) - 'id' as project
FROM "Things" t
 JOIN "Projects" p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

You can remove multiple columns that way:

```
SELECT t.id, to_jsonb(p) - array['id', 'some_column'] as project
FROM "Things" t
 JOIN "Projects" p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `json_build_object` function:

```
SELECT t.id, json_build_object('id', p.id, 'name', p.name) AS project
FROM "Things" t
INNER JOIN "Projects" p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```

Comment: I'll look into this more.  In actuality we have about 30 attributes returned for `project`.  Is there a way to not have to duplicate the attribute (`'id', p.id`, etc) each time using `json_build_object`?

Comment: If you want to include all columns from `project`, then `to_json` is the best option. If you want to select some of them, then I'm afraid there is not (simple) way to avoid listing them explicitly.

Comment: I am happy to list them explicitly (once), just would prefer to not do it twice for each.

Comment: Then you have to do something along the lines to what you suggested in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `row_to_json()` on chosen columns, a subquery is necessary, however it would be more natural and more readable (IMO) to use the subquery as a derived table (i.e. in the `FROM` clause):

```
SELECT t.id, row_to_json(p.*)
FROM "Things" t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, name
    FROM "Projects") p 
    ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE t.id = ?
```